# Select rows in Database with int type whose value is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, default-value

I am maintaing a project. There is a table called 'timeblock', it has a field called 'break_minutes', in the legacy design, the type for 'break_minutes' is int, and default value is NULL.

This design is not good for my new task, because i will use 'break_minutes' to do some math functions. like sum. So i have already changed the database schema and the default value to 0 not Null.

So I have to change all the data whose 'break_minutes' value is NULL to 0.

So I write the sql:

```
update timeblock set break_minutes=0 where break_minutes=NULL
```

and the result is empty.

if I write sql like:

```
update timeblock set break_minutes=0 where break_minutes=NULL
```

the result is only for the rows whose value is 0.

Both two sqls can't achieve my expectations.

Anyone who has the idea for that? thanks.

Comment: Don't you know how to accept answers

Comment: What is the difference in both query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check whether a value is **NULL**, use the special comparison predicates `IS NULL` instead of using comparison operators. 
Comparison operators return `unknown` when comparing anything with **NULL**.

```
UPDATE timeblock SET break_minutes=0 WHERE break_minutes IS NULL
```